# Difference between Utility and Helper classes

Tags: c#

Aren't utility classes really the same concept as helpers?  I mean utility methods don't extend an existing class such as helpers but the two types of methods really could be referred to as "Helpers" in either case.

Answer (score 11):

Utility classes are useful by itself; whereas helper classes are classes with extension methods which will help extend the types.

Answer (score 0):

Utility classes tend to be static methods and definitions, where as helper classes could be nodes in a linked list.  That is how I use the terminology.

Comment: when you say nodes you mean extending functionality of an existing method from another class for the helpers side of things?  I'm debating whether to just create a folder and classes called Helpers in my Web Projects vs. having both Utility and helper folders and classes in my web project.

Comment: I don't know about nodes in a linked list, but utility classes are indeed to be static (imo). A helper would be a good name when you use a delegation pattern for something.

Comment: Well I'm thinking in terms of ASP.NET helper methods vs. just C# Utility methods in their respective custom classes.  I guess I could look at it as if the method doesn't have anything to do with ASP.NET directly, that you could call it a Utility method.  Otherwise if it's "helping" you somehow in like an .aspx or .ascx and lets say just making life easier or providing you more options while using them in an .aspx or .acsx page then they are "helper methods"

Comment: To put it even simpler: you can instantiate helpers.  Utilities are a collection of methods, declarations and static variables.  That is how I see this terminology used.